# LINQ for Java tool

Tags: java, sql, mysql, linq

Would a LINQ for java be a useful tool?  I have been working on a tool that will allow a Java object to map to a row in a database.

1. Would this be useful for Java
   programmers?
2. What features would be
   useful?

Comment: For LINQ to objects, check this one: github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light, real example: new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).toList().distinct();

Comment: Scala LINQ: https://github.com/nicholas22/propelS

Answer (score 63, accepted):

LINQ for Java would be lovely, but the problem is the language integration.

Java doesn't have anything as concise as lambda expressions, and they're one of the bedrocks of LINQ. I suppose they *could* layer the query expression support on top of normal Java without lambda expressions, by making the expansion create anonymous inner classes - but it would be pretty hideous. You'd also need expression trees if you wanted to do anything like LINQ to SQL.

Checked exceptions *might* get in the way, but we'd have to see. The equivalent of IQueryable would need to have some sort of general checked exception - or possibly it could be generic in both the element type and the exception type...

Anyway, this is all pie-in-the-sky - given the troubles the Java community is having with closures, I think it would be folly to expect anything like LINQ in Java itself earlier than about 2012. Of course, that's not to say it wouldn't be possible in a "Java-like" language. Groovy has certain useful aspects already, for instance.

For the library side, Hibernate already provides a "non-integrated" version of a lot of the features of LINQ to SQL. For LINQ to Objects, you should look at the [Google Java Collections API](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) - it's a lot of the same kind of thing (filtering, projecting etc). Without lambdas it's a lot fiddlier to use, of course - but it's still really, really handy. (I use the Google Collections code all the time at work, and I'd hate to go back to the "vanilla" Java collections.)

Comment: what troubles are the java community experiencing with closures?

Comment: @Claudiu: Several proposals, none of them entirely satisfactory. Last I heard it sounded unlikely that it would even get into Java 7, due to there being so much discussion. This is a downside of Java being so democratic.

Comment: Where is an example of Projecting in the google collections api?

Comment: @Nathan: See Iterables.transform.

Comment: thanks, I figured it had to do with the transform method, I thought perhaps there might be some less manual approach, like a hibernate Projections kind of api.

Comment: Now Java has Lambdas, and JaQue (https://github.com/TrigerSoft/jaque) can produce Expression Trees out of them. So language integration is not a problem any more.

Comment: @KonstantinTriger: It's good to see that Java is catching up with where C# was so long ago - really, it is. I still prefer *compiler* support for expression trees to having a separate library which requires an implementation-specific system property to be set, and files to be generated and parsed at execution time...

Answer (score 14):

It's worth noting that [Scala 2.8 is going to have LINQ support](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.announce/154)...

---

Actually, scala standart collections provide API that works like LINQ-for-Objects in some sense. Here is the example:

```
List("Paris","Berlin","London","Tokyo")
  .filter(c => c.endsWith("n"))
  .map(c => c.length) 
// result would be length of the words that ends 
// with "n" letter ("Berlin" and "London").
```

Don't be scared of new-line-dot syntax: you can write code in plain old style:

```
Array(1,2,3,4,5,6).map(x => x*x)
```

And there is a number of projects that provide close to LINQ-to-SQL syntax. For example, snippet taken from Squeryll:

```
import Library._
using(session) { 
  books.insert(new Author(1, "Michel","Folco"))            
  val a = from(authors)(a=> where(a.lastName === "Folco") select(a)) 
}
// but note that there is more code behind this example
```

Comment: Seems like not yet, but here's hoping. Scala has done great feats before, like integrating XML into the language. And I hope it gets better :)

Answer (score 8):

For a more general approach to the issue, consider using [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com).

It provides a LINQ-style syntax with support for JPA/Hibernate, JDO, SQL and Java Collection backends.

I am the maintainer of Querydsl, so this answer is biased.

Answer (score 4):

Java [LINQ to SQL](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) implementation. Provides full language integration and larger feature set compared to .NET LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

**Hibernate** uses HQL. You can do Object but only for Relational Databases

Answer (score 0):

An extension to Java which gives LINQ-to-objects capabilities is [SBQL4J](http://code.google.com/p/sbql4j/).
It offers:

- Type-safety in compile time
- Powerful query engine with greater capabilities than LINQ
- Compatibility with current JVMs (it uses preprocessing to translate queries to pure Java code)
- Nice performance (no reflection is used at runtime)
- Clear, precise semantics without needless, obscure syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

Baby steps:

A first approach: implement Java LINQ using strings for expressions, instead of lambda.

Write `IQueryProviders` based on string expressions.

Then, pursue for add the string expressions directly in the language.

But first, I want a LINQ that works: typed linq in language, it's a nice thing, but the MAIN point is: have a way to write `IQueryProviders`, then, write a provider for [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)s, a provider for Hibernate, a provider for SQL Server or Oracle, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[Siena](http://www.sienaproject.com/) project seems good.