# Good examples of .NET (C#) open source projects ported to Java? ( C# -> Java )

Tags: c#, java, .net, open-source, naming-conventions

I notice several well-known projects in java that were ported to C# .NET. Some examples:

- Hibernate -> NHibernate
- JUnit --> NUnit
- Ant --> NAnt
- Lucene --> Lucene.Net, NLucene
- iText --> iTextSharp
- log4j --> log4net
- Quartz --> Quartz.NET

I was curious about the reverse situation:  what are the notable .NET projects that have been ported to the java world?

I looked at the list of projects at http://csharp-source.net but didn't see any obvious ones.

Comment: Most of these projects were ported to .NET simply because Java came first. But I am also curious...

Comment: Java has been around a lot longer and has been a favourite of open source community for a long time and has, therefore, a large number of useful projects. It's unlikely that something that's developed for .NET that isn't already available for JVM. Though I wish someone would port Terracotta Cluster to .NET.

Comment: Yes, Java came out in 1995 and C# in 2001.  Java has a 6 year head start but I don't see that preventing *new* creative programmers (after 2001) developing something useful originally as a C# project that was later cloned by the java community.  Maybe all java examples I cited happen to originate before 2001 (I didn't research the history of each one) which inadvertently makes the inquiry seem lopsided.

Comment: Generally items are ported after they become popular, which takes time.  Thus most ported items have been around for a while, which gives a greater advantage to Java.

Comment: Interesting. Probably it will help to first spot well know projects in .NET... does anyone have a source for that?

Comment: @Oscar Reyes. Paint.NET; http://banshee-project.org/; Both mainstream,multimedia-related(popular among non-technicians) and quite popular. It is interesting to spot applications, which do not have analogues in JAVA and i hardly believe that will be an easy task =)

Comment: In the case of standalone tools like nAnt and CruiseControl.NET, does anyone know *why* they get ported to .NET when the Java versions work just fine? Is it just for the fun of porting it?

Comment: And also **[Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know of .net ecosystem, the most missing part seems to be Linq, for which [this StackOverflow question provides some infos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346721/linq-for-java). In those answers, the most relevant seems to be [Quaere](http://quaere.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score -1):

[JaQu](http://h2database.com/html/jaqu.html) is another example