# Is there any LINQ like implementation in java?

Tags: c#, java, linq

Just like C# provides me LINQ, is there any package or pre-processor in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, no. Check out [Jon Skeet's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346721/linq-for-java-tool/346735#346735)

Answer (score 2):

Uhm... yes! See https://github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light

```
  // create alphabet char[]
  new Character('A').to(new Character('Z')).unbox();

  // join two arrays and put in list 
  alphabet.join(numerics).toList(); 

  // select distinct j* names, using LINQ-style statements
  new String[] { "james", "john", "john", "eddie" }.where(startsWith("j")).distinct();
```