# Java LINQ -like functionality

Tags: java, sql, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ for Java tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346721/linq-for-java-tool)

In C# there is a capability to use LINQ statements in order to access a Collection as if writing a SQL statement. I would like to create a similar plug-in for Java and was wondering you guys had any advice for how to go about doing this? I would like to make it as similar to SQL as possible.

Comment: Saw this on reddit today: https://github.com/nicholas22/jpropel-light

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I didn't see it!

Comment: "Link" in "C++"? What is that? Is it like LINQ in C#?

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I had not seen it, but this isn't specific to Java. Any Java specific advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is quite difficult to do in java since LINQ is built and integrated into the C# language. If I were to do this, I would probably create a class for all actions in MySQL: for example "Select", "Join"... and then make methods for actions you would like to conduct on them. Select(...).From  where "From" is a method on the Select class. This is a very simplified example of course, but what you need to do is create a SQL compiler in Java, and then add any custom methods or classes you would want.

A word of caution however, LINQ is more efficient than writing loops in C#, however if you were to write your own custom Java LINQ, you would simply be writing shortcuts. What I am trying to say is that, you will not be making your code any more efficient, simply more readable and compact.